# Swift3: Proper way to convert string to null-terminated C-string

Tags: swift, swift3

I am interfacing with libxml2 in swift, and the C APIs binding (still) produce `UnsafePointer<Int8>!` for c-strings. Whereas Swift APIs normally result in `UnsafePointer<UInt8>!`.

So my question is - am I doing the string to null-terminated C-string in a proper way?

```
let cfilePath = unsafeBitCast(myStringString.nulTerminatedUTF8.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress }, to: UnsafePointer<Int8>.self)
```

Should I instead prefer using some other method instead of just bypassing Swift type checking with interpreting `UInt8` bytes as `Int8` bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use unsafeBitCast for that!!

```
let cstr = "alpha".nulTerminatedUTF8
let int8arr = cstr.map{ Int8(bitPattern: $0) }
let uint8arr = Array(cstr)
print(int8arr.dynamicType, uint8arr.dynamicType)
// Array<Int8> Array<UInt8>
```

update

```
let uint8: UInt8 = 200
let int8 = Int8(bitPattern: uint8)
print(uint8, int8)
// 200 -56
```

Comment: This is not a good way I guess. Int8(bitPattern: $0) will produce runtime exception for numbers above 127, while UInt has range 0...255

Comment: excuse me, you are right, the init(bitPattern: ) will not produce the exception, I confused it with Int8(_ value:) ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this solves your problem exactly but for a project where I am sending strings over bluetooth this did the trick:

```
extension String {
    var nullTerminated: Data? {
        if var data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            data.append(0)
            return data
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use like this

```
let data = "asfasf".nullTerminated
```

I can't find the function the other answers are referencing: nulTerminatedUTF8. Maybe it already does this.